# Can we use resttemplate after upgrading Spring framework version from 4 to Spring 5/higher

Tags: spring

I am using spring 4.3.0 framework and use spring resttemplate to make restful webservice call. Kindly advise if we can continue to use resttemplate after upgrading Spring 4 to 5 or so.
If we cannot use then what would be the replacement of resttemplate in spring higher version. How can I make restful webservice.

Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? It is still there it isn't `@Deprecated` yet, it is only in maintenance mode, meaning no new features will be added.

Answer (score 0):

As metioned before you ca use it. We use it with Spring 5.3 as well and hadn't any issue. So just go on. ;)

Comment: Thank you @Deinum for your valuable advise :)

Comment: Thank you @T.Semmler for your advise and info